# i don´t know how acces to the pet object (EXCERCISE WITH OBJECTS IN JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, pojo

im doing a project-excercise of debugging using objects, im already done all the other´s excercises but im very stuck in this, i dont know how to solve.

```
    /*

Fix the `feedPet` function. `feedPet` should take in a pet name and return a
function that, when invoked with a food, will return the pet's name and a list
of foods that you have fed that pet.

*/

function feedPet(name) {
  const foods = [];
  return (food) => {
    return "Fed " + name + " " + foods.push(food) + ".";
  }
}

const feedHydra = feedPet('Hydra');

console.log(feedHydra('bones')); // Fed Hyrda bones.
console.log(feedHydra('Hercules')); // Fed Hyrda bones, Hercules.

const feedHippogriff = feedPet('Hippogriff');

console.log(feedHippogriff('worms')); // Fed Hyrda worms.
console.log(feedHippogriff('crickets')); // Fed Hyrda worms, crickets.
console.log(feedHippogriff('chicken')); // Fed Hyrda worms, crickets, chicken.
```

Comment: There first step is to read up on what `Array#push` returns: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push. You will see that it returns the new length of the array. But you want to print the current values of the array. So you have call `foods.push(food)` before you generate the string. Then you should find out how to convert an array to a string.

Answer (score 0):

`push` returns a new length of the array, but you want to have the items

```
function feedPet(name) {
  const foods = [];
  return (food) => {
    foods.push(food)
    return "Fed " + name + " " + foods + ".";
  }
}
```

```js
function feedPet(name) {
  const foods = [];
  return (food) => {
    foods.push(food)
    return "Fed " + name + " " + foods.join(', ') + ".";
  }
}

const feedHydra = feedPet('Hydra');

console.log(feedHydra('bones')); // Fed Hyrda bones.
console.log(feedHydra('Hercules')); // Fed Hyrda bones, Hercules.

const feedHippogriff = feedPet('Hippogriff');

console.log(feedHippogriff('worms')); // Fed Hyrda worms.
console.log(feedHippogriff('crickets')); // Fed Hyrda worms, crickets.
console.log(feedHippogriff('chicken')); // Fed Hyrda worms, crickets, chicken.
```

Answer (score 0):

foods.push(food) returns the array length, which is the reason for the numbers.

Fixed your code to print the array correctly:

```js
    /*

Fix the `feedPet` function. `feedPet` should take in a pet name and return a
function that, when invoked with a food, will return the pet's name and a list
of foods that you have fed that pet.

*/

function feedPet(name) {
  const foods = [];
  return (food) => {
    foods.push(food);
    
    // Equivalent to foods.join(", ");
    /*
    var ret = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < foods.length; ++i)
    {
      ret += foods[i];
      if(i < foods.length - 1)
      {
        ret += ", ";
      }
    }
    */

    return "Fed " + name + " " + foods.join(", ") + ".";
  }
}

const feedHydra = feedPet('Hydra');

console.log(feedHydra('bones')); // Fed Hyrda bones.
console.log(feedHydra('Hercules')); // Fed Hyrda bones, Hercules.

const feedHippogriff = feedPet('Hippogriff');

console.log(feedHippogriff('worms')); // Fed Hyrda worms.
console.log(feedHippogriff('crickets')); // Fed Hyrda worms, crickets.
console.log(feedHippogriff('chicken')); // Fed Hyrda worms, crickets, chicken.
```

Comment: There is no need to build a string from the array manually. You can just use `foods.join(', ')`.

Comment: @FelixKling You are right, I forgot that existed after writing too much Assembly haha